# SSMS (SQL) - sum function

Tags: sql-server, sum, ssms

I am fairly new to sql so please bare that in mind, I am looking to sum the total of two 'centers' for a specific column..

Here is my sql query;

```
select center, sum(convert(float,vol_ipm)) as Vol_Ipm
from example_Test
where daterange = '2016-11-01'
group by center
```

The results are displayed as:

```
Center:     Vol_Ipm:
Montreal    3000
Toronto     8500
```

I want to add the two centers together and get the total (sum) without having to manually add them up, would be great if I can get a temporary column populate with the total for montreal + toronto. I cannot seem to figure it out.

Any advice or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What is a "temporary column"?

Comment: Remove `Center` from your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` statement?

Comment: or add `sum(convert(float,vol_ipm)) over ()`

Comment: I'm also interested to know, if your converting `vol_ipm` to a `float`, what datatype is it now? I **hope** it isn't a `(n)varchar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just cut out the `center` column from your select:

```
select sum(convert(float,vol_ipm)) as Vol_Ipm
from example_Test
where daterange = '2016-11-01'
```

output:

```
Vol_Ipm:
11500
```

Answer (score 1):

Transact-SQL can do hierarchical rollup for the GROUP BY, so it will group by CENTER, but then also give you a NULL center that has the grand total.

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP( center )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the sum of all vol_ipm columns :

```
select sum(convert(float,vol_ipm)) as Vol_Ipm
from example_Test
where daterange = '2016-11-01'
```

If you want to keep your original query but have this total visible on each row than do this

```
select center, 
       convert(float,vol_ipm) as Vol_Ipm,
       (select sum(convert(float,vol_ipm)) from example_test where daterange = '2016-11-01') as Total
from example_Test
where daterange = '2016-11-01'
group by center
```

Also take care how you write your date format, always use a language neutral format. See this link http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes